# 'the left and right hand of Peter' or 'the left and right hands of Peter'?

Tags: singular-vs-plural

I know it is okay to say

> the left hand and the right hand of Peter

But what if I want to abbreviate it?

Answer (score 1):

Peter's left and right hands.

That's it.

English likes that format and **it's best to avoid "of" when possible.**

So, the book of Peter is really Peter's book.